# Trying to use mysql query inside of a php function to call data from database.

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a function called `tree()` which is supposed to retrieve data from my `comments` table and display comments in a thread in a hierarchy, much like the comments on reddit. The `$parentid` is the id of the parent comment and the `$postid` is the id of the page the comment is on. `DisplayComments()` is a php function which displays the comment's data and forms, including html.

Now the issue is when I load the page the php code stops at `$statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);` when it's done inside of the function. However, if I take the code outside of the function the code works, but I can't use the code inside of `DisplayComments()` and can only show the comment replies as if they were the start of new threads.

Why can't I use this mysql query inside of a function? Is there anyway I can use it inside of a function so I can call it where I need it?

```
function tree($parentid, $postid) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parentid = ?";
    $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('i', $parentid);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    if ($statement->error)
    {
        die('Database query failed: ' . $statement->error);
    }

    if ($statement->num_rows >= 1)
    {
        $statement->bind_result($commentid, $postid, $username, $comment, $parentid, $level);
        while($statement->fetch()){
            if (!is_hidden($commentid, 1)){ 
                DisplayComments($comment, $username, $postid, $commentid, $level);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to learn how to write a good code, learn about Data Mapper  / Repository pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tree function has no knowledge of `$databaseConnection`. You need to pass it as another variable, e.g.

```
function tree($parentid, $postid, $databaseConnection) {
```

Have a read of the [PHP manual's page on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) (but try not to use `global`, that's rarely a good thing)

Comment: It partially works. It displays one nested comment but now that comment has the previous issue. I should mention that `DisplayComment()` calls `tree()` inside of itself too so they loop around another.

Comment: This line `$statement->bind_result($commentid, $postid, $username, $comment, $parentid, $level);` contains more variables that are out of scope. You're going to need to pass those too

Comment: The bind-result is me passing the selected data from the database into variables. How are these out of scope?

Comment: No problem. Is there anything else you can see which I could fix?

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it! Instead of doing `function tree($parentid, $postid, $databaseConnection)` I just created a global variable and placed it in the function. Thanks for your help though!